# addEventListener does not respond

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn how to add JavaScript to my webpage. I tried this and it doesn't work. Could somebody please help me understand why?

```html
<NAV>
  <p>Click page to activate handler.</p>
  <script>
    addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log("Click worked");
    });
  </script>
</NAV>
```

I am trying to follow a tutorial at http://eloquentjavascript.net/14_event.html When I run the code on that page it works, but in my own webpage it doesn't. Is it because I have put it inside NAV?
It is supposed to show `Click worked` when I click on it.

Comment: The `addEventListener` method needs to attach itself onto a DOM element. Which element do you want to bind it to?

Comment: It's working for me http://jsfiddle.net/w9coat9L/. Do you see any error? What browser you're using to test?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi , do you think OP intended to add a click handler to the `window`?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney: The current code binds to the `window`. @HGamble: Your code snippet is working when we run it.

Comment: Welcome to stack! Nice job posting code you've tried. Define "doesn't work". In chrome, I see the log line since you are essentially attaching to the `window` object, with `useCapture` (3rd parameter of `addEventListener`) defaulting to `false`.

Comment: @spender: I don't know what he's trying to do, maybe he's just practicing. Provided question details, I have to say that code works as it is

Comment: @HGamble: Regarding your edit, we can't know why it doesn't work on your page if you don't provide all the info. What you have does work. Are you observing the output in the console? Are there any console errors?

Comment: I think I don't understand where I am supposed to observe the output. I assumed it would be on my webpage.

Comment: @HGamble The output will be shown in your browser's console. For example, press Ctrl+Shift+K on firefox or Ctrl+Shift+J on Chrome to open it. To show it in the webpage, try http://jsfiddle.net/w9coat9L/1/

Comment: OK. Thanks. I don't see what the point of outputting to the console is, but I understand that is why I didn't think it was working. Thanks Oriol for showing me that other code and also the jsfiddle site. I can't get that code to work on my page either, but I'll keep playing with it.